# What reference is needed to bind Word Documents through Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-word, reference

I'm programming over Access 2003 and Word.Application is unrecognized.

I tried a late binding declaring variable as Object and setting to a CreateObject("Word.Application") later, but it doesn't work.

I think I need some reference in the project :-S

Comment: "doesn't work" is not very descriptive.  What error do you get, and what does your code look like?

Comment: Well, when I say doesn't work I mean that don't recognize type as the early binding declaration Dim var as New Word.Application

Comment: I should have been clearer: I was asking about the problem with the late binding approach.  That should work if Word is installed.  If it doesn't work, it would help to see your code.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Word is installed but Access project doesn't have Word object library referenced. The problem was solved anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Strange, because "CreateObject" should work with late OR early binding. IOW, "Dim wordApp As Object: Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")" should have worked.

Comment: You mean? I think if Access doesn't have reference to Word is like Word is not installed because Access doesn't know about it. But I can't assure that I'm not very experience with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library fix the problem.

Comment: If you have a solution, please mark it as the answer, even if you answered your own question :)

Comment: yep I was waiting for 2 days limitation